# Vue : how to download a file to browser using the download tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using axios and want to download a PDF and an image file.

I can download both and open the image, but, when I try to open the PDF file, it doesn't open.

```
downloadItem({ url, name }) {
      axios
        .get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
        .then((response) => {
          const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.data.type });
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          link.download = name;
          link.click();
          URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    },
```

Can anybody help me ? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-download-file-using-axios-vue-jsexample.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
axios
.get(url, {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/pdf'
  },
  responseType: 'blob' })
.then(function (response) {
  switch ([WHAT IS YOUR TYPE]) {
    case "image": {
      const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.data.type });
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = name;
      link.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
      break
    }
    case "pdf": {
      const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
      const objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      window.open(objectUrl)
      elt.impressionEnCours = false
      break
    }
  }
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The pdf file was downloaded, when i try to open i get the message: Falha ao carregar o documento PDF.

Comment: I found the error,
Your solution solve the problem, thanks